# Why is IE not resolving host names in /etc/hosts but all other browsers does

Tags: php, internet-explorer, iis, wampserver

I have multiple hosts set up in /etc/hosts file in windows machine. My issue is that I am not able to access any of the host entries in /etc/hosts file in IE browsers. But I can access the hosts in all other browsers except IE browsers.

My host file looks like :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       apache.local.com
127.0.0.1       iis.local.com
```

If I take **apache.local.com** or **iis.local.com** in IE browser it just loads forever but in other browsers it loads fine and take me to the wamp server localhost page.

pinging those hosts looks ok

**ping apache.local.com**

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping apache.local.com

Pinging apache.local.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

**ping iis.local.com**

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping iis.local.com

Pinging iis.local.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

This is looking weird because other browsers works OK but only IE does have the issue it just loads forever.

I tried resetting the IE browser and flushed the DNS entries and rebooted the machine several time but still it does not work.

My system is **Windows8 64 bit** and have **wamp** and **IIS** with PHP and MySQL extensions installed.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: could refer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/30197/how-do-i-get-ie-to-use-my-hosts-file-when-using-a-proxy-pac-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. I see that if I start IIS server and visit the hosts in IE browsers everything worked fine. The issue happens only when I start Apache and browse on to that hosts.

My Apache version was 2.4.4. I switched to Apache 2.2.2 and everything worked fine. I think it would have been an issue with Apache 2.4.4. But I am still confused of the fact that it worked in other browsers, the issue was only with IE browsers.

Anyway switching on the Apache version did the trick for me.

Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try follwoing steps taking a note of fact that *

> Resetting will reset IE to factory settings. You'll lose your existing
>   configuration and any settings or data in IE. Judging by your love for
>   this browser, I'm assuming there isn't any data in there that you care
>   about. ;) However, be sure you're okay with this before following
>   these steps

*

Steps :

- Open Tools -> Internet Options
- Click on the "Advanced" tab.
- Click    "Reset"
- Click the checkbox for "Delete personal settings"
- In the    Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, click "Reset".
- When    changes are done, click "Close" and then restart the browser.

Comment: This because browsers load the hosts file into cache, the same goes for websites .htaccess files with redirect rules

Comment: I tried resetting the browser and restarting again. But it still does not work

Comment: did you restart IIS? or better still restart your machine!

Comment: I have tried both.  IIS hosts works fine. Suppose if I start IIS and take iis.local.com it works fine. The issue happens only with Apache.

Answer (score -1):

IPv6 may be something you want to look into here: https://superuser.com/questions/433258/ipv6-local-address-in-hosts-file

Could be IE is looking for IPv6 and the other browsers are using the traditional IPv4.

Comment: While IE does typically try to connect to IPv6 first, that's only going to happen if there's an IPv6 record present. In this case, only an IPv4 address is specified, so this shouldn't be relevant.